# SPARQL query fetch properties of resources

Tags: sparql, triplestore

I have a triple store and would like to create a query. This is an example of a resource representing a single deed:

```
<http://natarchives.com.mt/deed/MS588-D52>
    locah:accessProvidedBy  <http://natarchives.com.mt/repository/MT01> ;
    locah:associatedWith    "heredes" , "honorabilis" , "uncias" , "per tactum penne" , "vinea" , "ut moris est" , "juribus" , "unciarum" , "precij" , "spacium" , "gracia" , "tabernam sitam" , "honorabili" , "renunciantes" , "territorio" , "testes" , "tarenos" , "recuperacionis consuetudinarie" , "positam" , "ponderis" , "post" , "tabernam" , "causa" , "per se" , "sed sponte jure" , "diaconus" , "cisterna" , "precio" , "civitate" , "festo" , "solvere" ;
    locah:associatedWith    <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11817> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11826> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11822> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11820> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11823> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11818> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place486> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11824> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11825> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11821> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11816> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/place/place886> , <http://natarchives.com.mt/person/person11819> ;
    locah:level             <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/page/level/item> ;
    dcterms:date            "1-10-1467" ;
    dcterms:identifier      "MS588-D52" ;
    dcterms:isPartOf        <http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/MS588> ;
    dcterms:type            "Emptio" .
```

I am trying to search the deed by date. The result should show:

deed id, type, register URI - in this case (http://natarchives.com.mt/archivalresource/MS588), register Id, repository URI (http://natarchives.com.mt/repository/MT01), repository name, keywords associated with the deed and the people and places associated with deed. For people and places I would like to get other properties such as name, surname. This is what I have so far:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX locah: <http://data.archiveshub.ac.uk/def/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT  ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName ?associatedEntities                       
WHERE                                                                          
{
 {
    {
  SELECT ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName (group_concat(concat(str(?places)," @ ",?placeName); separator=" | ") as ?associatedEntities) 
  WHERE {
    ?x dcterms:date "22-1-1487".
    ?x dcterms:identifier ?id.
    ?x dcterms:type ?type.
    ?x locah:associatedWith ?places.
    ?places schema:name ?placeName.
    ?x dcterms:isPartOf ?register.
    ?register dcterms:identifier ?regId.
    ?x locah:accessProvidedBy ?rep.
    ?rep rdfs:label ?repName.
    FILTER (isURI(?places)).
    }
GROUP BY ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName
}union{
     SELECT ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName (group_concat(concat(str(?persons)," @ ",?name); separator=" | ") as ?associatedEntities) 
  WHERE {
    ?x dcterms:date "22-1-1487".
    ?x dcterms:identifier ?id.
    ?x dcterms:type ?type.
    ?x locah:associatedWith ?persons.
    ?persons foaf:firstName ?name.
    ?x dcterms:isPartOf ?register.
    ?register dcterms:identifier ?regId.
    ?x locah:accessProvidedBy ?rep.
    ?rep rdfs:label ?repName.
    FILTER (isURI(?persons)).
    }
      GROUP BY ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName
    }

  }

}
```

I managed to get both but is it possible to group the results of the union

Comment: *"What I cannot get are the URI of persons and places along with their properties. Any help please?"* - why not? It's the same as with the other information. Just add the triple patterns.

Comment: And regarding the data, why is the same property `locah:associatedWith` used for keywords and persons? That's poor modeling.

Comment: It would be good if you don't change queries while I'm answering ... and yes, why should it not be possible to use `GROUP BY` for the outer query?

Comment: I am trying to solve it as well and thus that is why I updated the result...it shows effort

Comment: then just add the group by to the outer query. It's the same as you did for the sub-queries

Comment: If I add GROUP BY ?id ?type ?register ?regId ?rep ?repName  after the last } I am getting an error: 
Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?associatedEntities

Comment: Yeah, of course ... you are not using an aggregate function on it, thus, you have to group by it. The question is, what do you expect as final result? You're using the the same variable `associatedEntities` which doesn't make sense? Why is the the first not called `associatedKeywords`? If you really want this, what should be the result? I mean, you want only one row per ID, but you have two values due two 2 sub-queries. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes I think I got it...thank you so much

Comment: Ok, cool. If you have the final query, please provide it as an answer. This might help other users having similar problems.